# CSS for print media not working in Firefox

Tags: css, firefox, printing

I have a page for which the users want to take out the print. I have prepared the css style with  @media print tag, that works in the Chrome and IE perfectly but not working in Firefox.

If I make 70% in in print preview in the Firefox it shows correct output. How should I implement the css for firefox only in print media that would zoom out to 70%?

Comment: Can you attach the CSS code in your question? And if possible a snippet on for example [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net)

Comment: Please have a look at : https://jsfiddle.net/gLLajr61/

Comment: Were you able to see that fiddle?

Comment: Yes, but I can't find the mistake for now.. Maybe someone else can spot it.

Comment: Okay, thanks for the input. :-)